# MySQL group by and Where

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

I want to add a where clause to the sql below so that the column called "howmany" only shows results that are greater than 1, but I keep getting an error when i try.

```
 select monthname(birthdate) as 'Month', Count(*) as howmany
 from tblBday
 group by month(birthdate)
 ;
```

Comment: should we guess, or simply extract the text of the error message from your brain telepathically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can't use an alias in a WHERE clause

Also, you can't do an aggregate function in a WHERE clause

You need something like this

```
SELECT monthname(birthdate) as Month, Count(*) AS howmany
FROM tblBday
GROUP BY month(birthdate)
HAVING Count(*) > 1
 ;
```

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) a tuto about HAVING

Comment: Thank you so much not just for the answer, but also the explanation! I didnt know you couldnt have an aggregate function in a Where clause. I found the link really helpful; exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an alias in a `WHERE` clause, and since you want to use an aggregate function then you need a `HAVING` clause:

```
select monthname(birthdate) as `Month`, Count(*) as howmany
from tblBday
group by month(birthdate)
having Count(*) > 1
```

If want to use an alias in a `WHERE` clause, then you can make your query a subquery:

```
select `month`, howmany
from
(
    select monthname(birthdate) as `Month`, Count(*) as howmany
    from tblBday
    group by month(birthdate)
) src
where howmany > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select monthname(birthdate) as 'Month', Count(*) as howmany
                                ^--   ^--
```

you can't quote aliases like that. single quotes (`'`) turn things into strings - strings aren't aliases, and can't be aliases. remove the quotes, or use backticks:

```
select monthname(birthdate) as Month, Count(*) as howmany
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select monthname(birthdate) as 'Month', Count(*) as howmany
from tblBday
group by month(birthdate)
having howmany > 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select monthname(birthdate) as 'Month', Count(*) as howmany
 from tblBday
 group by monthname(birthdate)
Having count(*) > 1
;
```